# Can I have many desktop environment in one operating system (Ubuntu)?

Tags: xfce, desktop-environments, cinnamon

I have laptop with only 4GB RAM and it's Ubuntu-installed. Can I have many desktop environment in one operating system, in this case Ubuntu without counting many user on it?. I am not sure what desktop environment I will use, like Cinnamon, KDE, XFCE, and others.

Comment: You can install multiple DEsktops on a system, but there maybe costs involved with it... Myself I'm a lover of it, my originally Ubuntu Desktop system I'm using now had `xubuntu-desktop` (Xfce), `lubuntu-desktpo` (it was LXDE but is now LXQt), `ubuntu-mate-desktop` (MATE) added to it & I select at login I use. I *love* that I can do it, but it's not without costs; and when multiple DEs are to be installed - the order & release you're asking about do matter in my experience (I installed mine 3 times to work out best order of adding desktop; & I gave up `kubuntu-desktop too which was more tries)

Comment: FYI:  I still use boxes which only have 1GB of RAM, but have more than enough disk space for multiple DEs to be installed; so I'll choose what I use in a session on those boxes by what apps I'll use in the session... Part of the costs being wasting RAM; and with 1GB that really matters... I'm careful with apps when I'm using boxes with <5GB of RAM like you have, and whilst multiple DEs can help with this, if you're not aware of DE & Tk/libs being used by apps/DE you risk wasting RAM with poor choices... ie. benefits/cost will depend on your knowledge too).

Comment: The cleanest option is probably to try out different DEs from live-usbs first, then install the single one you liked the most.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can install several DE. Previously some DE caused compatibility issue so do a little research first. Try them all and let us know what you think. For low resource systems I like XFCE, but surprisingly KDE is pretty light on RAM usage.